# Оператор, принимающий левый операнд типа std::basic_istream

Tags: ооп, операторы, c++

Здравствуйте. Работаю с ооп, хочу избавиться от public-переменных и сделать геттеры и сеттеры. Однако в паре случаев получаю такую ошибку. Как избавиться?

```
input >> theStar.getName() >>
         theStar.getPlace().x >> theStar.getPlace().y >>
         theStar.getRadius();

input >> inputPlanet.getName() >>
         inputPlanet.getPlace().x >> inputPlanet.getPlace().y >>
         inputPlanet.getRadius();
```

"Не найден оператор, принимающий левый операнд типа `"std::basic_istream<_Elem,_traits>"` (или приемлемое преобразование отсутствует)".

Comment: Вторая строчка-пример криво скопировалась, вот так она выглядит:
input>>inputPlanet.getName()>>inputPlanet.getPlace().x>>inputPlanet.getPlace().y>>inputPlanet.getRadius();

Comment: а что у Вас возвращают getName, getPlace и так далее? какой тип?

Comment: getName - string
getPlace - coordinate (структура)
getRadius - double

getPlace().x и getPlace().y - соотв. double

Comment: @Whiteenr: тогда что-то не так. Попробуйте (временно) разбить на части:

   input >> inputPlanet.getName();
   input >> inputPlanet.getPlace().x;
   input >> inputPlanet.getPlace().y;
   input >> inputPlanet.getRadius();

и скажите, какая строка не компилируется.

Comment: Так не компилируются все, кроме самой первой во втором выводе. В вопросе я не написал, там цикл, идущий сразу после первого input   while (!input.eof()) 

        {
                input >> inputPlanet.getName();
    input >> inputPlanet.getPlace().x;
    input >> inputPlanet.getPlace().y;
    input >> inputPlanet.getRadius();
    planets.push_back(inputPlanet);
        }

В первом выводе ошибки "необъявленный идентификатор" и "выражение слева должно представлять структуру, класс и т.д.", во втором - "не найден оператор >>, принимающий левый операнд..."

Comment: Что-то странное. Напишите, пожалуйста, минимальный законченный пример, воспроизводящий проблему. Один класс + функция `main`.